# How to Convert Rows to Columns And Fill the data from another table

Tags: sql

I have three tables dbo.Student col(StudentID,Student Name and

```
Subjects                Test
---------------         ----------------
subjectId int           StubjectId int foreignkey from Subjects
Subject Name            StudentID int  foreignkey from Student
                        Marks int
```

Now I need to display the test Result As

```
Student Name     Math   Geo 
----------------------------
Michael          90     67
```

Comment: Look up for `Pivot` in whatever RDBMS you are working with

Answer (score 0):

When you post SQL question, please include script for schema and test data

You initial SQL will be something like

```
select name, subjectname, marks
    from test t
    inner join student s on t.studentid = s.studentid
    inner join subject su on t.subjectid = su.subjectid
```

and [then you will need to pivot it 2 times](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/)

Comment: can u please show me the fast way to pivot those rows because i'm new to sql programming